# In customer projects, must I specify myself or the customer in <meta name="author">?

Tags: html

By other words, must "author" refers the engineer or it means the customer?

> the name of the document's author.

is all that said about it in [Standard metadata names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name) article of MDN.

Comment: It is not you. I do not see the value for the customer to have some developer's name in their meta data.

Comment: @mplungjan, thank you for the comment. By the verdict is "It must refer to the customer"?

Comment: Or be empty or not set. Ask the customer. Perhaps they have a communications department they want in there. I do not believe the Author meta tag is interesting to anyone

Comment: Consensus on the SEO websites seems to be that the Author meta tag is ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify yourself as the name of the author as it is will indicate the author of that HTML document.

In large projects it will be easier to track who wrote what. In away it will be easier to maintain and apply changes. If you specify customer as an author it will distinguish it from your other projects but not the files inside the project.

- Suppose a team of three developers were assigned the task to develop a specific website each author will wrote his name as an author. So as to easily recognised.
- If there was only one programmer and in future somebody else is assigned still it will be easy to know who was the original writer or at least how many people were involved in development of original website (front end)

Comment: Don't we already have a tool named "Source Control Management" to find authors of a document ?

Comment: Yes we do have those but there is nothing wrong with having another option and as name="author" is very specific and will mostly only tell about frontend devloper.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to specify the developer's name in code. But the `<meta name="author">` HTML element is NOT design for that purpose. It is intended to store the author of the "document", IE the author of the text present on that page.

For example on a blog post page it will store the author of the blog post.